# Optimize nested inner joins

Tags: sql, postgresql, typeorm

The following TypeORM generated SQL query takes over 11 sec to complete :

```
SELECT "node"."node_id" AS "node_id",
    "node"."updated_on" AS "updated_on",
    "node"."lang" AS "lang",
    "node"."second_lang" AS "second_lang",
    "node"."title" AS "title",
    "node"."execution_modes" AS "execution_modes",
    "artifact"."current_rev" AS "current_rev",
    "artifact"."created_on" AS "created_on",
    "artifact"."reference" AS "reference",
    "ac_program"."name" AS "ac_program_name",
    "release_in_production"."rgti_revision" AS "release_in_production_rgti_revision",
    "release_in_production"."name" AS "release_in_production_name",
    "release_in_production"."in_production_date" AS "release_in_production_date",
    "last_release"."id" AS "review_release_id",
    "node"."root_id" AS "root_id",
    (("last_release"."status" = 'CHECK_IN_PROGRESS'
            AND "last_release_checker"."id" IS NOT NULL
            AND "last_release_checker"."review_date" IS NULL) OR("last_release"."status" = 'APPROVAL_IN_PROGRESS'
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                AND "last_release_approver"."id" IS NOT NULL
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                AND "last_release_approver"."review_date" IS NULL)) AS "has_pending_review",
    CASE
                    WHEN "last_release"."rgti_revision" = "artifact"."current_rev"
                                        AND "last_release"."status" = 'IN_PRODUCTION' THEN 'DASHBOARD_STATUS_RELEASED'
                    WHEN "last_release"."rgti_revision" = "artifact"."current_rev"
                                        AND "last_release"."status" = 'CHECK_IN_PROGRESS' THEN 'DASHBOARD_STATUS_CHECK_IN_PROGRESS'
                    WHEN "last_release"."rgti_revision" = "artifact"."current_rev"
                                        AND "last_release"."status" = 'APPROVAL_IN_PROGRESS' THEN 'DASHBOARD_STATUS_APPROVAL_IN_PROGRESS'
                    WHEN "last_release"."rgti_revision" = "artifact"."current_rev"
                                        AND "last_release"."status" = 'APPROVED' THEN 'DASHBOARD_STATUS_APPROVED'
                    WHEN "rev"."status" = 'CANCELED' THEN 'DASHBOARD_STATUS_CANCELED'
                    ELSE 'DASHBOARD_STATUS_WORK_IN_PROGRESS'
    END AS "status"
FROM "test_root_node" "node"
LEFT JOIN "test_root_revision_node" "node_target_revision_data" ON "node_target_revision_data".ROOT_ID = "node".ROOT_ID
AND "node_target_revision_data".START_REV =
    (SELECT MAX(START_REV)
        FROM "test_root_revision_node"
        WHERE ROOT_ID = "node".ROOT_ID
            AND STATUS IN ('PUBLISHED',
                                                                            'RELEASED',
                                                                            'CANCELED'))
LEFT JOIN "test_root_artifact" "artifact" ON "artifact"."root_id" = "node"."root_id"
LEFT JOIN "ext_usr_user" "created_by" ON "created_by"."username" = "artifact"."created_by"
LEFT JOIN "ext_spf_ac_program" "ac_program" ON "ac_program"."id" = "artifact"."ac_program_id"
LEFT JOIN "test_root_revision_node" "rev" ON "rev"."root_id" = "artifact"."root_id"
AND (("rev"."start_rev" <= "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev"
                        AND ("rev"."end_rev" IS NULL
                                            OR "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev" < "rev"."end_rev")))
LEFT JOIN "ext_usr_user" "owner" ON "owner"."username" = "node"."owner"
LEFT JOIN "ext_usr_user" "updated_by" ON "updated_by"."username" = "node"."updated_by"
LEFT JOIN "release" "release_in_production" ON "release_in_production"."root_id" = "node"."root_id"
AND "release_in_production"."rgti_revision" =
    (SELECT MAX("lastreleasedsub"."rgti_revision")
        FROM "release" "lastreleasedsub"
        WHERE "lastreleasedsub"."root_id" = "node"."root_id"
            AND "lastreleasedsub"."status" = 'IN_PRODUCTION')
LEFT JOIN "release" "last_release" ON "last_release"."root_id" = "node"."root_id"
AND "last_release"."rgti_revision" =
    (SELECT MAX("subrelease"."rgti_revision")
        FROM "release" "subrelease"
        WHERE "subrelease"."root_id" = "node"."root_id")
LEFT JOIN "release_checker" "last_release_checker" ON "last_release_checker"."releaseId" = "last_release"."id"
AND "last_release_checker"."user" = $1
LEFT JOIN "release_approver" "last_release_approver" ON "last_release_approver"."releaseId" = "last_release"."id"
AND "last_release_approver"."user" = $2
WHERE ("node"."start_rev" <= "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev"
                            AND ("node"."end_rev" IS NULL
                                                OR "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev" < "node"."end_rev"))
    AND EXISTS
        (SELECT 1
            FROM "test_root_node" "sub_node"
            LEFT JOIN "r_test_root_node_ext_spf_prod_site" "sub_node_sub_sites" ON "sub_node_sub_sites"."node_object_id" = "sub_node"."object_id"
            LEFT JOIN "ext_spf_prod_site" "sub_sites" ON "sub_sites"."id" = "sub_node_sub_sites"."ext_id"
            WHERE ("sub_node"."start_rev" <= "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev"
                                        AND ("sub_node"."end_rev" IS NULL
                                                            OR "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev" < "sub_node"."end_rev"))
                AND "sub_node"."node_id" = "node"."node_id"
                AND "sub_sites"."id" IN ($3,
                                        $4,
                                        $5,
                                        $6,
                                        $7,
                                        $8,
                                        $9,
                                        $10))
ORDER BY "artifact"."reference" ASC NULLS FIRST
LIMIT 10;
```

Given the following database indexes :

```
"table_name"    "index_name"    "column_name"
"attachment_node"   "pk_7122c15632e3fcc73b05e1469a1"    "object_id"
"chapter_node"  "UQ_2d0c8eed0c372d42d7869e4342d"    "start_rev"
"chapter_node"  "UQ_2d0c8eed0c372d42d7869e4342d"    "node_id"
"chapter_node"  "pk_3af2e67c786c8eeaf80813962c5"    "object_id"
"ext_data"  "PK_c7f24c9babbc3720df7a872aed3"    "id"
"ext_data_metadata" "PK_b23dcef2a424f213e81db02286a"    "id"
"ext_ref_ata"   "pk_b631c9d4aee24712830048347f2"    "code"
"ext_ref_ca"    "pk_2a80f7e8b3e7373cac24f23fbdf"    "code"
"ext_ref_fin"   "pk_78fcd46235cc23f3ee0100724eb"    "code"
"ext_ref_skill" "pk_2d74c6f76a209e1c36cf3c4d42c"    "code"
"ext_spf_ac_program"    "pk_920689a78eec92b1d3df0778917"    "id"
"ext_spf_logical_station"   "PK_4b06ae89b75a82eea4c9d4b6597"    "id"
"ext_spf_prod_site" "pk_3903558ebb361b80dd910f279c9"    "id"
"ext_tag"   "pk_b3854f993092dacbf46550b2f4f"    "id"
"ext_usr_user"  "pk_9c530ad1f37e2a16dcc8cf87377"    "username"
"external_link_node"    "pk_5a45e83762204e743e8ffe0b02e"    "object_id"
"r_test_description_node_chapter_node"  "IDX_05e0f7d1f1d6a3ed69efa395d7"    "child_node_id"
"r_test_description_node_chapter_node"  "IDX_2d532fdf79f618d8968be9a01c"    "parent_node_id"
"r_test_description_node_chapter_node"  "pk_ee9ecf26f6d13535119096c686e"    "parent_node_id"
"r_test_description_node_chapter_node"  "pk_ee9ecf26f6d13535119096c686e"    "child_node_id"
"r_test_procedure_node_test_unit_node"  "IDX_02fd2faaaa95ecbc79b800580e"    "child_node_id"
"r_test_procedure_node_test_unit_node"  "IDX_43277ef8ec99e6849961e6f753"    "parent_node_id"
"r_test_procedure_node_test_unit_node"  "pk_6b1b30f65aeb1ea38f7d4c5054c"    "parent_node_id"
"r_test_procedure_node_test_unit_node"  "pk_6b1b30f65aeb1ea38f7d4c5054c"    "child_node_id"
"r_test_root_node_attachment_node"  "IDX_023d1ccb57bf62eb0e416c9a57"    "child_node_id"
"r_test_root_node_attachment_node"  "IDX_1afd533b8e0225d34aa4296f66"    "parent_node_id"
"r_test_root_node_attachment_node"  "pk_b71b09716e34babc1d909bb2596"    "child_node_id"
"r_test_root_node_attachment_node"  "pk_b71b09716e34babc1d909bb2596"    "parent_node_id"
"r_test_root_node_compatible_st"    "IDX_1b084bb256388137e8dacc6a4f"    "node_object_id"
"r_test_root_node_compatible_st"    "IDX_5c7b084d4be5d3cdb76ecd21f5"    "ext_id"
"r_test_root_node_compatible_st"    "PK_a2f2908df7c3c388077d1e6f7c3"    "node_object_id"
"r_test_root_node_compatible_st"    "PK_a2f2908df7c3c388077d1e6f7c3"    "ext_id"
"r_test_root_node_ext_ref_ata"  "IDX_15a68018d69beb38bdfa69b70c"    "node_object_id"
"r_test_root_node_ext_ref_ata"  "IDX_cf116974d178ad630b66ecd1f8"    "ext_id"
"r_test_root_node_ext_ref_ata"  "pk_eb4ac377637f5ceb6b90bcf0c1b"    "ext_id"
"r_test_root_node_ext_ref_ata"  "pk_eb4ac377637f5ceb6b90bcf0c1b"    "node_object_id"
"r_test_root_node_ext_ref_ca"   "IDX_d6407cff145959ca53bdae1b67"    "ext_id"
"r_test_root_node_ext_ref_ca"   "IDX_ee0f5a6fed3a63b556930e9580"    "node_object_id"
"r_test_root_node_ext_ref_ca"   "pk_ba7ec25548904cd793d9e780fe2"    "ext_id"
"r_test_root_node_ext_ref_ca"   "pk_ba7ec25548904cd793d9e780fe2"    "node_object_id"
"r_test_root_node_ext_ref_fin"  "IDX_9e594314b9a706ec52aa227b00"    "node_object_id"
"r_test_root_node_ext_ref_fin"  "IDX_ac8952cd8cbf2424a839f51b86"    "ext_id"
"r_test_root_node_ext_ref_fin"  "pk_ef72ac007e236fdcfb354dfcce8"    "node_object_id"
"r_test_root_node_ext_ref_fin"  "pk_ef72ac007e236fdcfb354dfcce8"    "ext_id"
"r_test_root_node_ext_spf_prod_site"    "IDX_4ab972ad15555172e68e01c047"    "ext_id"
"r_test_root_node_ext_spf_prod_site"    "IDX_d7461b317b01d414d72ef1921d"    "node_object_id"
"r_test_root_node_ext_spf_prod_site"    "pk_8deb35a540a1740c59fb4ec09d9"    "node_object_id"
"r_test_root_node_ext_spf_prod_site"    "pk_8deb35a540a1740c59fb4ec09d9"    "ext_id"
"r_test_root_node_ext_tag"  "IDX_a1af2f18b63c38bae16eea0117"    "ext_id"
"r_test_root_node_ext_tag"  "IDX_eaa5a7223fc32ef14285260b24"    "node_object_id"
"r_test_root_node_ext_tag"  "pk_142d28e8680266144d30bf5b9af"    "ext_id"
"r_test_root_node_ext_tag"  "pk_142d28e8680266144d30bf5b9af"    "node_object_id"
"r_test_root_node_external_link_node"   "IDX_9345d21892e27e9a49214e2bc1"    "parent_node_id"
"r_test_root_node_external_link_node"   "IDX_d8a27de16f8f9f7ee7a2752ebb"    "child_node_id"
"r_test_root_node_external_link_node"   "pk_c24fdc9d19be4184714af742ac4"    "child_node_id"
"r_test_root_node_external_link_node"   "pk_c24fdc9d19be4184714af742ac4"    "parent_node_id"
"r_test_root_node_logical_st"   "IDX_8641c5a17185cdad9d16a99589"    "node_object_id"
"r_test_root_node_logical_st"   "IDX_8b932582af835ebbb533868556"    "ext_id"
"r_test_root_node_logical_st"   "PK_17a7361140b5326cf4faff83a82"    "ext_id"
"r_test_root_node_logical_st"   "PK_17a7361140b5326cf4faff83a82"    "node_object_id"
"r_test_root_node_test_description_node"    "IDX_81d33a6a9563c41577478d3fb7"    "parent_node_id"
"r_test_root_node_test_description_node"    "IDX_b1a1d9076d2c19f1b961aae7e5"    "child_node_id"
"r_test_root_node_test_description_node"    "pk_803a0f6bf3aadbd497a10b83685"    "parent_node_id"
"r_test_root_node_test_description_node"    "pk_803a0f6bf3aadbd497a10b83685"    "child_node_id"
"r_test_root_node_test_procedure_node"  "IDX_a6a416d8ab88e2d53ddfa35e0b"    "child_node_id"
"r_test_root_node_test_procedure_node"  "IDX_ab832058fe3cd089c2ca954216"    "parent_node_id"
"r_test_root_node_test_procedure_node"  "pk_e7037371e536c9034a52c73c6bf"    "child_node_id"
"r_test_root_node_test_procedure_node"  "pk_e7037371e536c9034a52c73c6bf"    "parent_node_id"
"release"   "PK_1a2253436964eea9c558f9464f4"    "id"
"release_approver"  "PK_8679d35b0b83d5528c791eff3de"    "id"
"release_checker"   "PK_bf6acbf084e68d6777aacc5e9e4"    "id"
"release_comment"   "PK_fecf4efcbd373bfe8efb169a20a"    "id"
"report"    "PK_99e4d0bea58cba73c57f935a546"    "id"
"test_description_node" "UQ_2be180cda3ed4488dcfba3db5d5"    "start_rev"
"test_description_node" "UQ_2be180cda3ed4488dcfba3db5d5"    "node_id"
"test_description_node" "pk_77a1e6f9e8ef568cc503aa291d3"    "object_id"
"test_procedure_node"   "UQ_f35233791742eaf7f3e69bc064d"    "start_rev"
"test_procedure_node"   "UQ_f35233791742eaf7f3e69bc064d"    "node_id"
"test_procedure_node"   "pk_57f51bcf74a4175322a7dd193bd"    "object_id"
"test_root_artifact"    "pk_0a59a848eada13a258968f056b2"    "root_id"
"test_root_history" "PK_487fa43ef42115f91b5e0d35e93"    "id"
"test_root_node"    "UQ_1aff647d44dff994820090ae31f"    "node_id"
"test_root_node"    "UQ_1aff647d44dff994820090ae31f"    "start_rev"
"test_root_node"    "pk_54a38aaa1312a11f60c78340fb8"    "object_id"
"test_root_revision_node"   "IDX_fd47296459998d846f8aaf5d7c"    "root_id"
"test_root_revision_node"   "IDX_fd47296459998d846f8aaf5d7c"    "status"
"test_root_revision_node"   "IDX_fd47296459998d846f8aaf5d7c"    "start_rev"
"test_root_revision_node"   "PK_ebfe64a40be8b84ba0b11f20148"    "object_id"
"test_root_revision_node"   "UQ_9203c83320251254c301b461fcc"    "start_rev"
"test_root_revision_node"   "UQ_9203c83320251254c301b461fcc"    "node_id"
"test_root_updater_backup"  "PK_1fff2d2064b28ecabebd59eb5f3"    "id"
"test_root_updater_backup"  "UQ_4f7e4f45e3176ff030d98cbd03a"    "user"
"test_root_updater_backup"  "UQ_4f7e4f45e3176ff030d98cbd03a"    "root_id"
"test_unit_node"    "UQ_983f4c5181620ed69c4b1d30c16"    "node_id"
"test_unit_node"    "UQ_983f4c5181620ed69c4b1d30c16"    "start_rev"
"test_unit_node"    "pk_93c0e29964aa0071fff9584eb74"    "object_id"
```

It feels like some left joins could be indexed, but I am unsure how to do it the proper way.
Besides from indexing, is there anything I could do from TypeORM (or other), to really speed up the request?

Here is the EXPLAIN output :

```
"Limit  (cost=1069379.70..1069379.73 rows=10 width=719)"
"  ->  Sort  (cost=1069379.70..1069382.09 rows=955 width=719)"
"        Sort Key: artifact.reference NULLS FIRST"
"        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1056844.28..1069359.06 rows=955 width=719)"
"              Join Filter: (last_release_approver.""releaseId"" = last_release.id)"
"              ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=1056844.28..1069316.62 rows=955 width=744)"
"                    Join Filter: (last_release_checker.""releaseId"" = last_release.id)"
"                    ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=1056844.28..1069300.45 rows=955 width=720)"
"                          Merge Cond: ((node.root_id = release_in_production.root_id) AND (((SubPlan 3)) = release_in_production.rgti_revision))"
"                          ->  Sort  (cost=1056824.45..1056826.84 rows=955 width=702)"
"                                Sort Key: node.root_id, ((SubPlan 3))"
"                                ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=1045162.88..1056777.18 rows=955 width=702)"
"                                      Merge Cond: ((node.root_id = last_release.root_id) AND (((SubPlan 4)) = last_release.rgti_revision))"
"                                      ->  Sort  (cost=1045143.04..1045145.43 rows=955 width=668)"
"                                            Sort Key: node.root_id, ((SubPlan 4))"
"                                            ->  Hash Semi Join  (cost=4242.36..1045095.77 rows=955 width=668)"
"                                                  Hash Cond: (node.node_id = sub_node.node_id)"
"                                                  Join Filter: ((sub_node.start_rev <= node_target_revision_data.start_rev) AND ((sub_node.end_rev IS NULL) OR (node_target_revision_data.start_rev < sub_node.end_rev)))"
"                                                  ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2290.10..1043100.04 rows=8424 width=672)"
"                                                        ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=2289.69..1035188.46 rows=754 width=672)"
"                                                              Join Filter: (ac_program.id = artifact.ac_program_id)"
"                                                              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=2289.69..1033603.66 rows=754 width=158)"
"                                                                    ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=2237.79..2535.94 rows=19808 width=162)"
"                                                                          Merge Cond: (node.root_id = artifact.root_id)"
"                                                                          ->  Sort  (cost=2222.76..2272.28 rows=19808 width=134)"
"                                                                                Sort Key: node.root_id"
"                                                                                ->  Seq Scan on test_root_node node  (cost=0.00..809.08 rows=19808 width=134)"
"                                                                          ->  Sort  (cost=15.03..15.55 rows=207 width=46)"
"                                                                                Sort Key: artifact.root_id"
"                                                                                ->  Seq Scan on test_root_artifact artifact  (cost=0.00..7.07 rows=207 width=46)"
"                                                                    ->  Index Only Scan using ""IDX_fd47296459998d846f8aaf5d7c"" on test_root_revision_node node_target_revision_data  (cost=51.90..52.04 rows=1 width=20)"
"                                                                          Index Cond: ((root_id = node.root_id) AND (start_rev >= node.start_rev) AND (start_rev = (SubPlan 2)))"
"                                                                          Filter: ((node.end_rev IS NULL) OR (start_rev < node.end_rev))"
"                                                                          SubPlan 2"
"                                                                            ->  Result  (cost=51.48..51.49 rows=1 width=4)"
"                                                                                  InitPlan 1 (returns $1)"
"                                                                                    ->  Limit  (cost=0.41..51.48 rows=1 width=4)"
"                                                                                          ->  Index Only Scan Backward using ""IDX_fd47296459998d846f8aaf5d7c"" on test_root_revision_node  (cost=0.41..357.88 rows=7 width=4)"
"                                                                                                Index Cond: ((root_id = node.root_id) AND (start_rev IS NOT NULL))"
"                                                                                                Filter: ((status)::text = ANY ('{PUBLISHED,RELEASED,CANCELED}'::text[]))"
"                                                              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..12.10 rows=140 width=524)"
"                                                                    ->  Seq Scan on ext_spf_ac_program ac_program  (cost=0.00..11.40 rows=140 width=524)"
"                                                        ->  Index Scan using ""IDX_fd47296459998d846f8aaf5d7c"" on test_root_revision_node rev  (cost=0.41..10.38 rows=11 width=40)"
"                                                              Index Cond: ((root_id = artifact.root_id) AND (start_rev <= node_target_revision_data.start_rev))"
"                                                              Filter: ((end_rev IS NULL) OR (node_target_revision_data.start_rev < end_rev))"
"                                                  ->  Hash  (cost=1692.48..1692.48 rows=20782 width=24)"
"                                                        ->  Hash Join  (cost=1057.83..1692.48 rows=20782 width=24)"
"                                                              Hash Cond: (sub_node_sub_sites.node_object_id = sub_node.object_id)"
"                                                              ->  Hash Join  (cost=1.15..581.23 rows=20782 width=16)"
"                                                                    Hash Cond: ((sub_node_sub_sites.ext_id)::text = (sub_sites.id)::text)"
"                                                                    ->  Seq Scan on r_test_root_node_ext_spf_prod_site sub_node_sub_sites  (cost=0.00..475.77 rows=25977 width=33)"
"                                                                    ->  Hash  (cost=1.10..1.10 rows=4 width=82)"
"                                                                          ->  Seq Scan on ext_spf_prod_site sub_sites  (cost=0.00..1.10 rows=4 width=82)"
"                                                                                Filter: ((id)::text = ANY ('{CC,BB,AA,A,B,C,D,E}'::text[]))"
"                                                              ->  Hash  (cost=809.08..809.08 rows=19808 width=40)"
"                                                                    ->  Seq Scan on test_root_node sub_node  (cost=0.00..809.08 rows=19808 width=40)"
"                                                  SubPlan 4"
"                                                    ->  Aggregate  (cost=9.43..9.44 rows=1 width=4)"
"                                                          ->  Seq Scan on release subrelease  (cost=0.00..9.43 rows=3 width=4)"
"                                                                Filter: (root_id = node.root_id)"
"                                      ->  Sort  (cost=19.83..20.52 rows=274 width=50)"
"                                            Sort Key: last_release.root_id, last_release.rgti_revision"
"                                            ->  Seq Scan on release last_release  (cost=0.00..8.74 rows=274 width=50)"
"                                      SubPlan 3"
"                                        ->  Aggregate  (cost=10.12..10.13 rows=1 width=4)"
"                                              ->  Seq Scan on release lastreleasedsub  (cost=0.00..10.11 rows=3 width=4)"
"                                                    Filter: ((root_id = node.root_id) AND ((status)::text = 'IN_PRODUCTION'::text))"
"                          ->  Sort  (cost=19.83..20.52 rows=274 width=34)"
"                                Sort Key: release_in_production.root_id, release_in_production.rgti_revision"
"                                ->  Seq Scan on release release_in_production  (cost=0.00..8.74 rows=274 width=34)"
"                    ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.85 rows=1 width=40)"
"                          ->  Seq Scan on release_checker last_release_checker  (cost=0.00..1.85 rows=1 width=40)"
"                                Filter: ((""user"")::text = 'test'::text)"
"              ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..1.85 rows=1 width=40)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on release_approver last_release_approver  (cost=0.00..1.85 rows=1 width=40)"
"                          Filter: ((""user"")::text = 'test'::text)"
"JIT:"
"  Functions: 115"
"  Options: Inlining true, Optimization true, Expressions true, Deforming true"
```

TypeORM code :

```
const query: AlmQueryBuilder<TestRootNodeEntity> = this.almManager.createQueryBuilder({
            targetStatus: [TestRootStatusEnum.PUBLISHED, TestRootStatusEnum.RELEASED, TestRootStatusEnum.CANCELED]
        });
        query.from(TestRootNodeEntity, 'node');

        // common joins from test root attributes
        query
            .leftJoin('node.artifact', 'artifact')
            .leftJoin('artifact.created_by', 'created_by')
            .leftJoin('artifact.ac_program', 'ac_program')
            .leftJoin('artifact.revisions', 'rev') // It's a list but alm will retrieve only one revision
            .leftJoin('node.owner', 'owner')
            .leftJoin('node.updated_by', 'updated_by');

        // Last release in production
        query.leftJoin(
            ReleaseEntity,
            'release_in_production',
            'release_in_production.root_id = node.root_id AND release_in_production.rgti_revision = ' +
                this.sqGetReleaseInProductionRevision(query, 'node.root_id')
        );

        // Last release of the rgti
        query.leftJoin(
            ReleaseEntity,
            'last_release',
            'last_release.root_id = node.root_id AND last_release.rgti_revision = ' +
                this.sqGetMaxReleaseRevision(query, 'node.root_id')
        );

        // Last release - user checker if present
        query.leftJoin(
            ReleaseCheckerEntity,
            'last_release_checker',
            'last_release_checker.release.id = last_release.id ' + 'AND last_release_checker.user.username = :username',
            { username }
        );

        // Last release - user approver if present
        query.leftJoin(
            ReleaseApproverEntity,
            'last_release_approver',
            'last_release_approver.release.id = last_release.id ' +
                'AND last_release_approver.user.username = :username',
            { username }
        );

        query
            .select('node.node_id', 'node_id')
            .addSelect('node.root_id', 'root_id')
            .addSelect('artifact.reference', 'reference')
            .addSelect('artifact.created_on', 'created_on')
            .addSelect('artifact.current_rev', 'current_rev')
            .addSelect('ac_program.name', 'ac_program_name')
            .addSelect('node.updated_on', 'updated_on')
            .addSelect('node.lang', 'lang')
            .addSelect('node.second_lang', 'second_lang')
            .addSelect('node.title', 'title')
            .addSelect('node.execution_modes', 'execution_modes')
            .addSelect('release_in_production.name', 'release_in_production_name')
            .addSelect('release_in_production.in_production_date', 'release_in_production_date')
            .addSelect('release_in_production.rgti_revision', 'release_in_production_rgti_revision')
            .addSelect(this.queryHasPendingReview(), 'has_pending_review')
            .addSelect('last_release.id', 'review_release_id')
            .addSelect(this.queryDashboardStatus(), 'status');

        query.offset(isNil(pagination.offset) ? 0 : pagination.offset);
        query.limit(isNil(pagination.limit) ? 50 : pagination.limit);
```

Feel free to ask for more information.

Comment: Here is EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) output : https://pastebin.com/mxn3vRuE

Comment: By vacuuming do you mean removing some useless data from them? Thank you for your help.

Comment: PostgreSQL has a command named "VACUUM".  I mean to run that command.  (It also has a system to vacuum automatically, but maybe that is not working sufficiently for you. 
 First see if doing it manually fixes the problem.)

Comment: Can you give us the real definitions of the indexes?  Especially IDX_fd47296459998d846f8aaf5d7c.  The order of columns matters, and we can't see the order from the format you used.

Comment: Vacuum did help, reduced query time to 5.5 sec! How could I turn on track_io_timing? What information do you need about that index? I am not sure how to get more info.

Comment: You have to be a superuser to turn on track_io_timing.  You can do it in your interactive session (using the SET command) or my preference just turn it on globally in postgresql.conf.  You can get the index definition from the "pg_indexes" view, or from the psql `\d` command, or from the output of `pg_dump -s`.  I would need to know what the order of the columns in the index is.

Comment: Here's the list of indexes from the pg_indexes table. Hope this helps. https://pastebin.com/mganGVn6

Comment: That seems to be only indexes on the system/catalog tables.  Or in any case, I can't find  IDX_fd47296459998d846f8aaf5d7c on test_root_revision_node

Comment: Right, here's the pg_indexes table for the correct database : https://pastebin.com/mQkJphYe. Please not I've addeed 2 indexes as suggested by @Edouard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2 fold speed up from vacuuming is nice, but I thought it would be much more than that.

Far more than half the original time is going to this one node, so even with a 2 fold speed it still must be slow.

```
Index Only Scan Backward using ""IDX_fd47296459998d846f8aaf5d7c"" on test_root_revision_node  (cost=0.41..357.88 rows=7 width=4) (actual time=0.472..0.472 rows=1 loops=19835)"
    Index Cond: ((root_id = node.root_id) AND (start_rev IS NOT NULL))"
    Filter: ((status)::text = ANY ('{PUBLISHED,RELEASED,CANCELED}'::text[]))"
    Rows Removed by Filter: 1026"
    Heap Fetches: 20376052"
    Buffers: shared hit=15008089"
```

What this is doing is jumping to the end of the part of the index where root_id has the desired value, walking backwards down the order of start_rev until it finds the first row which meets `status=ANY ('{PUBLISHED,RELEASED,CANCELED}')` condition, then stopping.  And on average it has to walk down over 1026 entries with the wrong status before finding one entry with a right status.  I don't know if that is because those statuses are very rare, or because they are biased to occur only early on in the sequence of start_rev.

The ideal index for this case would be:

```
CREATE INDEX ON public.test_root_revision_node (root_id, start_rev) 
    where status in ('PUBLISHED','RELEASED','CANCELED')
```

With that index, it should be able to pull out the max value of start_rev which has the correct status, for each given root_id, pretty much immediately.  And if those statuses are rare, then this index should also be pretty small.

Of course if those three listed statuses are not set in stone, but were just selected from a list of checkboxes and will be different each time, then this index won't be much of a solution for you.

That is my bottom up analysis.  Edouard's top down analysis is also good, and it would be nice to know if you adopted any of those changes and how they worked.

Comment: Your answer helped reduce query time to a little more than 1s. Which is a great improvement! I couldn't really implement Edouard's changes as I couldn't make them work or translate to TypeORM.

Comment: @Maxime B - I'm a bit disappointed by your last comment. I spent a couple of hours to analyse your case and provide you many directions to search for improvements. If you implemented succesfully your initial query with TypeORM, you should be able to update it according to my suggestions. I would like you to go all the way so that to know the impact of some redesign on the performances, hoping that we can get much more than 10% of improvement. I'm ready to continue to support you in that way.

Comment: I did not redact the initial query, but been in charge to optimize it in a efficient way. Indexing and vaccuuming sped up the request 10 folds. Doing it faster would be great, but I am unsure how I could implement your changes in the current TypeORM code. I'll update the question with typeORM code.

Comment: @jjanes, the index creation is causing lock issues. Database never finishes request and dropping index is hanging. What could cause this?

Answer (score 2):

Some comments and proposals for rethinking that monster query :

**(A) Removing the `LEFT JOIN`ed tables which are not used in the rest of the query**

Several `LEFT JOIN`ed tables are not used in the rest of the query so they could simply be removed from the query :

```
LEFT JOIN "ext_usr_user" "created_by" ON "created_by"."username" = "artifact"."created_by"
LEFT JOIN "ext_usr_user" "owner" ON "owner"."username" = "node"."owner"
LEFT JOIN "ext_usr_user" "updated_by" ON "updated_by"."username" = "node"."updated_by"
```

**(B) Optimizing some temporal statements using the range types**

There are several similar statements like

```
("node"."start_rev" <= "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev" AND ("node"."end_rev" IS NULL OR "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev" < "node"."end_rev"))"
```

which can be replaced by

```
tsrange("node"."start_rev", "node"."end_rev") @> "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev"
```

in order to avoid the `OR` clause which may be more expensive than `AND`.

`tsrange()` is used if `start_rev` and `end_rev` are of type `Timestamp without time zone`, or it must be replaced by `tstzrange()` for `Timestamp with time zone` type or `daterange()` for `date` type.

Note that when `"node"."end_rev" IS NULL` then the upper bound of `tsrange("node"."start_rev", "node"."end_rev")` is the infinity so that the condition `tsrange("node"."start_rev", "node"."end_rev") @> "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev")` is always true when `"node_target_revision_data"."start_rev" >= "node"."start_rev"` is true.

This change may apply to :

(1) the `ON` clause of `LEFT JOIN "test_root_revision_node" "rev"` :

```
LEFT JOIN "test_root_revision_node" "rev"
  ON "rev"."root_id" = "artifact"."root_id"
AND tsrange("rev"."start_rev", "rev"."end_rev") @> "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev"
```

(2) the first part of the final `WHERE` clause :

```
WHERE tsrange("node"."start_rev", "node"."end_rev"= @> "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev"
```

(3) the subquery in the second part of the final `WHERE` clause :

```
WHERE tsrange("sub_node"."start_rev", "sub_node"."end_rev") @> "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev"
```

In order to adapt the existing indexes to these query changes, you can replace some of them by new ones :

```
-- this new index replaces "UQ_1aff647d44dff994820090ae31f"
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index_name ON "test_root_node"
USING GiST (node_id, tsrange(start_rev, end_rev)) ;

-- this new index replaces "IDX_fd47296459998d846f8aaf5d7c"
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS index_name ON "test_root_revision_node"
USING GiST (root_id, tsrange(start_rev, end_rev)) ;
```

**(C) The subquery in the final WHERE clause looks like overweight**

The subquery (`SELECT 1 FROM "test_root_node" "sub_node" ...)` will provide rows coming from the main table `"test_root_node"` whatever what exists (or not) in both `LEFT JOIN`ed tables `"r_test_root_node_ext_spf_prod_site"` and `"ext_spf_prod_site"`. So both `LEFT JOIN`ed tables sounds like useless in this specific subquery and could be removed as weel as their corresponding conditions in the `WHERE` clause. As a consequence, this subquery could be simplified as :

```
AND EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
     FROM "test_root_node" "sub_node"
    WHERE tsrange("sub_node"."start_rev", "sub_node"."end_rev") @> "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev"
      AND "sub_node"."node_id" = "node"."node_id"
  )
```

But looking one step further, if the main query

```
SELECT *
 FROM "test_root_node" "node"
 LEFT JOIN "test_root_revision_node" "node_target_revision_data"
   ON "node_target_revision_data"."root_id" = "node"."root_id"
  AND "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev" =
    ( SELECT MAX(START_REV)
        FROM "test_root_revision_node"
        WHERE ROOT_ID = "node".ROOT_ID
          AND STATUS IN ('PUBLISHED','RELEASED','CANCELED'))
WHERE int4range("node"."start_rev", "node"."end_rev") @> "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev"
```

returns one or more rows, then for each of these rows, the following condition will be true because the returned rows conform that condition :

```
EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
     FROM "test_root_node" "sub_node"
    WHERE tsrange("sub_node"."start_rev", "sub_node"."end_rev") @> "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev"
      AND "sub_node"."node_id" = "node"."node_id"
  )
```

So finally this subquery just looks like redundant with the first part of the main `WHERE` clause which could be reduced as follow :

```
WHERE tsrange("node"."start_rev", "node"."end_rev") @> "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev"
```

**(D) Redesigning `LEFT JOIN "test_root_revision_node" "node_target_revision_data"`**

The full `ON` clause can be reintegated into the `LEFT JOIN` which becomes `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` due to the reference to `"node"."root_id"`, `"node"."start_rev"` and `"node"."end_rev"` in the `WHERE` clause :

```
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
   ( SELECT "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev"
       FROM "test_root_revision_node" "node_target_revision_data" 
      WHERE "node_target_revision_data"."root_id" = "node"."root_id"
        AND "node_target_revision_data"."status" IN ('PUBLISHED','RELEASED','CANCELED')
        AND tsrange("node"."start_rev", "node"."end_rev") @> "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev"
      ORDER BY "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev" DESC
      LIMIT 1
   ) "node_target_revision_data"
  ON True
```

The references to the `node` table's columns can also be externalized so that to come back to a `LEFT JOIN` form :

```
LEFT JOIN
   ( SELECT "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev"
       FROM "test_root_revision_node" "node_target_revision_data" 
      WHERE "node_target_revision_data"."status" IN ('PUBLISHED','RELEASED','CANCELED')
      ORDER BY "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev" DESC
      LIMIT 1
   ) "node_target_revision_data"
  ON "node_target_revision_data"."root_id" = "node"."root_id"
 AND tsrange("node"."start_rev", "node"."end_rev") @> "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev"
```

**(E) Fatal blow to the final `WHERE` clause**

Comparing the results of (C) and (D), it appears obviously that the final `WHERE` clause is just redundant with part of the `WHERE` clause in the first `LEFT JOIN LATERAL`, so that the final `WHERE` clause looks like useless and can be fully removed from the final query.

**(F) Redesigning `LEFT JOIN "release" "release_in_production"`**

Similar to (D), the full `ON` clause can be reintegated into the `LEFT JOIN` which becomes `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` due to the reference to `"node"."root_id"` in the `WHERE` clause :

```
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
   ( SELECT "release_in_production"."name"
          , "release_in_production"."rgti_revision"
          , "release_in_production"."in_production_date"
       FROM "release" "release_in_production"
      WHERE "release_in_production"."root_id" = "node"."root_id"
        AND "release_in_production"."status" = 'IN_PRODUCTION'
      ORDER BY "release_in_production"."rgti_revision" DESC
      LIMIT 1
   ) "release_in_production"
  ON True
```

The references to the `node` table's columns can also be externalized so that to come back to a `LEFT JOIN` form :

```
LEFT JOIN
   ( SELECT "release_in_production"."name"
          , "release_in_production"."rgti_revision"
          , "release_in_production"."in_production_date"
       FROM "release" "release_in_production"
      WHERE "release_in_production"."status" = 'IN_PRODUCTION'
      ORDER BY "release_in_production"."rgti_revision" DESC
      LIMIT 1
   ) "release_in_production"
  ON "release_in_production"."root_id" = "node"."root_id"
```

**(G) Redesigning `LEFT JOIN "release" "last_release"`**

Similar to (D), the full `ON` clause can be reintegated into the `LEFT JOIN` which becomes `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` due to the reference to `"node"."root_id"` in the `WHERE` clause :

```
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
   ( SELECT "last_release"."id"
          , "last_release"."status"
          , "last_release"."rgti_revision"
       FROM "release" "last_release"
      WHERE "last_release"."root_id" = "node"."root_id"
      ORDER BY "last_release"."rgti_revision" DESC
      LIMIT 1
   ) "last_release"
  ON True
```

The references to the `node` table's columns can also be externalized so that to come back to a `LEFT JOIN` form :

```
LEFT JOIN
   ( SELECT "last_release"."id"
          , "last_release"."status"
          , "last_release"."rgti_revision"
       FROM "release" "last_release"
      ORDER BY "last_release"."rgti_revision" DESC
      LIMIT 1
   ) "last_release"
  ON "last_release"."root_id" = "node"."root_id"
```

**(H) Redesigning `LEFT JOIN "release_checker" "last_release_checker"`**

The `ON` clause refers to the variable `$1` which should appear either in the final `WHERE` clause of the query, or into this `LEFT JOIN` clause which becomes `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` due to the reference to `"last_release"."id"` if the full `ON` clause is reintegrated into the `WHERE` clause of the `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` :

```
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
   ( SELECT "last_release_checker"."id"
          , "last_release_checker"."review_date"
       FROM "release_checker" "last_release_checker"
      WHERE "last_release_checker"."releaseId" = "last_release"."id"
        AND "last_release_checker"."user" = $1
   ) "last_release_checker"
  ON True
```

**(I) Redesigning `LEFT JOIN "release_approver" "last_release_approver"`**

Similar to (H), the full `ON` clause can be reintegated into the `LEFT JOIN` which becomes `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` due to the reference to `"last_release"."id"` in the `WHERE` clause :

```
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
   ( SELECT "last_release_approver"."id"
          , "last_release_approver"."review_date"
       FROM "release_approver" "last_release_approver"
      WHERE "last_release_approver"."releaseId" = "last_release"."id"
        AND "last_release_approver"."user" = $2
   ) "last_release_approver"
  ON True
```

**(J) Taking the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` clauses into account**

The `LIMIT 10` clause is directly linked to the `ORDER BY "artifact"."reference" ASC NULLS FIRST` clause which involves only two tables in the `FROM` clause so that to be executed :

```
FROM "test_root_node" "node"
LEFT JOIN "test_root_artifact" "artifact"
  ON "artifact"."root_id" = "node"."root_id"
```

So the idea here is to isolate this part of the query in a [cte](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-SELECT) in order to dramatically limit the number of resulting rows to 10, these rows will be stored in a temporary table, and then to join the other tables for the final result :

```
WITH limited_list AS
(
    SELECT "node".*
         , "artifact"."created_by"
         , "artifact"."created_on"
         , "artifact"."updated_by"
         , "artifact"."reference"
      FROM "test_root_node" "node"
      LEFT JOIN "test_root_artifact" "artifact"
       ON "artifact"."root_id" = "node"."root_id"
    ORDER BY "artifact"."reference" ASC NULLS FIRST
    LIMIT 10
)
SELECT [the rest of the final SELECT clause]
  FROM limited_list AS l
  LEFT JOIN [the rest of the FROM clause]
```

**(K) Improving the query planning time**

There are still many LEFT JOINed tables in the query so that the pg planner may spend a lot of time to investigate the best plan to be executed, even if the `LEFT JOIN LATERAL` force the order in the execution. A preferential order could be explicitly defined so that to help the planner in finding the best plan quicker.

**(L) Final result of the analysis**

The final query may look like :

```
WITH limited_list AS
(
    SELECT "node".*
         , "artifact"."created_by"
         , "artifact"."created_on"
         , "artifact"."updated_by"
         , "artifact"."reference"
      FROM "test_root_node" "node"
      LEFT JOIN "test_root_artifact" "artifact"
       ON "artifact"."root_id" = "node"."root_id"
    ORDER BY "artifact"."reference" ASC NULLS FIRST
    LIMIT 10
)    SELECT l."node_id" AS "node_id",
    l."updated_on" AS "updated_on",
    l."lang" AS "lang",
    l."second_lang" AS "second_lang",
    l."title" AS "title",
    l."execution_modes" AS "execution_modes",
    l."current_rev" AS "current_rev",
    l."created_on" AS "created_on",
    l."reference" AS "reference",
    "ac_program"."name" AS "ac_program_name",
    "release_in_production"."rgti_revision" AS "release_in_production_rgti_revision",
    "release_in_production"."name" AS "release_in_production_name",
    "release_in_production"."in_production_date" AS "release_in_production_date",
    "last_release"."id" AS "review_release_id",
    l."root_id" AS "root_id",
    (   ("last_release"."status" = 'CHECK_IN_PROGRESS'
            AND "last_release_checker"."id" IS NOT NULL
            AND "last_release_checker"."review_date" IS NULL)
      OR("last_release"."status" = 'APPROVAL_IN_PROGRESS'
            AND "last_release_approver"."id" IS NOT NULL
            AND "last_release_approver"."review_date" IS NULL)
    ) AS "has_pending_review",
    CASE
      WHEN "last_release"."rgti_revision" = l."current_rev"
       AND "last_release"."status" = 'IN_PRODUCTION' 
      THEN 'DASHBOARD_STATUS_RELEASED'
      WHEN "last_release"."rgti_revision" = l."current_rev"
       AND "last_release"."status" = 'CHECK_IN_PROGRESS'
      THEN 'DASHBOARD_STATUS_CHECK_IN_PROGRESS'
      WHEN "last_release"."rgti_revision" = l."current_rev"
       AND "last_release"."status" = 'APPROVAL_IN_PROGRESS'
      THEN 'DASHBOARD_STATUS_APPROVAL_IN_PROGRESS'
      WHEN "last_release"."rgti_revision" = l."current_rev"
       AND "last_release"."status" = 'APPROVED'
      THEN 'DASHBOARD_STATUS_APPROVED'
      WHEN "rev"."status" = 'CANCELED'
      THEN 'DASHBOARD_STATUS_CANCELED'
      ELSE 'DASHBOARD_STATUS_WORK_IN_PROGRESS'
    END AS "status"
FROM limted_list AS l
LEFT JOIN
   ( SELECT "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev"
       FROM "test_root_revision_node" "node_target_revision_data" 
      WHERE "node_target_revision_data"."status" IN ('PUBLISHED','RELEASED','CANCELED')
      ORDER BY "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev" DESC
      LIMIT 1
   ) "node_target_revision_data"
  ON "node_target_revision_data"."root_id" = l."root_id"
 AND tsrange(l."start_rev", l."end_rev") @> "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev"
LEFT JOIN "ext_spf_ac_program" "ac_program"
  ON "ac_program"."id" = l."ac_program_id"
LEFT JOIN "test_root_revision_node" "rev"
  ON "rev"."root_id" = l."root_id"
 AND tsrange("rev"."start_rev", "rev"."end_rev") @> "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev"
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
   ( SELECT "release_in_production"."name"
          , "release_in_production"."rgti_revision"
          , "release_in_production"."in_production_date"
       FROM "release" "release_in_production"
      WHERE "release_in_production"."root_id" = l."root_id"
        AND "release_in_production"."status" = 'IN_PRODUCTION'
      ORDER BY "release_in_production"."rgti_revision" DESC
      LIMIT 1
   ) "release_in_production"
  ON True
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
   ( SELECT "last_release"."id"
          , "last_release"."status"
          , "last_release"."rgti_revision"
       FROM "release" "last_release"
      WHERE "last_release"."root_id" = l."root_id"
      ORDER BY "last_release"."rgti_revision" DESC
      LIMIT 1
   ) "last_release"
  ON True
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
   ( SELECT "last_release_checker"."id"
          , "last_release_checker"."review_date"
       FROM "release_checker" "last_release_checker"
      WHERE "last_release_checker"."releaseId" = "last_release"."id"
        AND "last_release_checker"."user" = $1
   ) "last_release_checker"
  ON True
LEFT JOIN LATERAL
   ( SELECT "last_release_approver"."id"
          , "last_release_approver"."review_date"
       FROM "release_approver" "last_release_approver"
      WHERE "last_release_approver"."releaseId" = "last_release"."id"
        AND "last_release_approver"."user" = $2
   ) "last_release_approver"
  ON True ;
```

**(M) `LATERAL JOIN` is maybe not optimal for performances**

The final query still includes many lateral joins which are usually not the winners in the performance race. Most of them could be converted back to `LEFT JOIN` by extracting the conditions in their `WHERE` clause which explicitly refer to the other joined tables and putting them into the `ON` clause of the resurrected `LEFT JOIN`.

**(N) Warning**

Obviously I cannot neither check if the final query is working, nor providing the expected result, nor demonstrating that the performances will be improved, but I hope that this analysis will provide some directions for improvement and/or redesign. Any feedback will be appreciated.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! The start_rev and end_rev aren't timestamp, thus tsranges is not working. I'll be trying to implement some of your ideas to see how it goes. Do you have anything regarding indexes?

Comment: Index is a long story which may need some tests to check their usage during the execution. First you should optimize the design of the query and then look at the indexes. What is the type or format off `start_rev` & `end_rev` ?

Comment: Those two fields are integers.

Comment: ok so you can replace `tsrange` by `int4range`

Comment: "But looking one step further, we can see that both aliases "node" and "sub_node" refer to the same "test_root_node" table"  I think this part of your analysis may be flawed, because those two aliases might refer to different rows at any one time.  node_id is not by itself a unique key of the table, so they might point to different revisions of the same node_id.

Comment: @jjanes - I completely agree with you in the general case, but in that specific query, I do think that the condition `EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM "test_root_node" "sub_node"
    WHERE ...)` is redundant with the `FROM "test_root_node" "node"
 LEFT JOIN "test_root_revision_node" "node_target_revision_data"
   ON ...` clause and the `WHERE tsrange("node"."start_rev", "node"."end_rev") @> "node_target_revision_data"."start_rev"` clause of the main query. I've updated the (C) section in the answer trying to make the thinking clearer.